# Trigger delete cache of url

Tags: caching, 8

I've two api url

- /api/v1/get-list
- /api/v1/post-item

In API url /api/v1/get-list I was set cache like this:

```
$build = [
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['url','url.query_args'],
    'max-age' => 3600,
  ],
];

$res = new ResourceResponse($response, 200);
$cache_metadata = CacheableMetadata::createFromRenderArray($build);
$res->addCacheableDependency($cache_metadata);
```

Response will be cache in one hour with url **/api/v1/get-list?_format=josn**. When I use api **/api/v1/post-item** response of **/api/v1/get-list** will changed value. But response was cached in one hour. So how to trigger delete cache of url when use orther url. I find some code

```
\Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();
```

but just for current request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a cache tag to the response of **/api/v1/get-list**:

```
$build = [
  '#cache' => [
    'contexts' => ['url','url.query_args'],
    'max-age' => 3600,
    'tags' => ['api-v1-list'],
  ],
];
```

and then invalidate this tag in **/api/v1/post-item**:

```
\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags(['api-v1-list']);
```